# Use github-actions as an user for automated pull requests

Tags: github, bots, github-actions, pull-request

I noticed that the automated pull requests that I implemented in open source project takes the admin as the one of the pull request. Ideally, if it was open by a bot then `github-actions` should be the one who opens pull request.

This makes the actions more transparent for everyone. I have not figured out how to change that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using the [create-pull-request](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/create-pull-request) action. Here is an example:

```yaml
jobs:
  createPullRequest:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Make changes to pull request
        run: date +%s > report.txt

      - name: Create Pull Request
        id: cpr
        uses: peter-evans/create-pull-request@v4
        with:
          token: ${{ secrets.PAT }}
          commit-message: Update report
          committer: GitHub <noreply@github.com>
          author: ${{ github.actor }} <${{ github.actor }}@users.noreply.github.com>
          signoff: false
          branch: example-patches
          delete-branch: true
          title: '[Example] Update report'
          body: |
            Update report
            - Updated with *today's* date
            - Auto-generated by [create-pull-request][1]

            [1]: https://github.com/peter-evans/create-pull-request
          labels: |
            report
            automated pr
          assignees: peter-evans
          reviewers: peter-evans
          team-reviewers: |
            owners
            maintainers
          milestone: 1
          draft: false
```

Here is a demonstration:

[image: GitHub Pull Request created by a GitHub Bot via GitHub Actions]

Comment: But who is the committer of this action? My problem is to link the commit to a person and not to the bot.

Comment: Do you know how can I commit as the bot and not as one of the authors?

Comment: Its already present in the action with the committers field

Comment: 1 year later but does anyone know how I can have the PR creator be the gituib-actions bot? I am trying to open a PR on another private org repo using this action and when I use my PAT it opens the PR as my personal user. I want to open it as github-actions[bot]  and when I use GITHUB_TOKEN I get an error that git cannot find the remote repo.

Comment: @MartinOLeary you can create an APP and use the APP to generate a access token